# How to retrieve files of User using user id in flutter firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

How do I get user id of Users when authenticated ? and will the files be stored in different collection for every user since every user is different. And finally how do I show a user his data like his images and posts when Logged In ?

Answer (score 0):

If your user is authenticated with Firebase using any provided auth method by Firebase, you can get the user id in that way:

```
String get currUid => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid ?? "";
```

If you authenticated successfully, then a definite userId will come there. In that case, you can write as

```
String get currUid => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, umm can you please let me know more about the " ! " after current user, why do we need to mention it can be null at first place and what are its uses  @Samarpan Dasgupta

Comment: @MOBILESRECOVERY due to null safety we uses that symbols(?. or !.). When we not sure about the result value is null or not we use ?. along with ?? symbol(First answer). 

if we sure that result value can't be null, we can use !. symbol